# How can I prevent \n showing in text in Mule

Tags: json, mule, anypoint-studio

I am returning a JSON message and it is showing the \n new line character.  How can I stop this from happening and show the return so the text looks more readable instead of just everything on a line?

An example text returned is:

> customers who bought this also bought:\n\n- Mario Kart

I am using  Anypoint Studio 6.1 and Mule 3.8.1

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you can use JavaScript on your results, use [`.replace()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) method:

> ```
> ("customers who bought this also bought:\n\n- Mario Kart").replace(/\n/g, '');
> ```

Answer (score 0):

From the question what i understood is :

1. You dont want \n to appear in the output, and
2. Also you want to replace \n with actual linebreak so that your output looks more beautiful.

You can actually do that.Here is how to achieve this with example.

I create a very simple flow and took two payload transformer (see Images).

In first set payload i am just assigning the value

customers who bought this also bought:\n\n- Mario Kart

[Click to see the flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hgTP.png)

In the second set payload i am again doing something like

## [payload.replace("\n", System.getProperty("line.separator"))]

[Click to see the flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qz3XC.png)

and this produces a formatted result .

Hope this helps ....

Answer (score 0):

Using dataweave, you can do like this

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
payload replace "\n" with " "
```